# html - Allow break string in '/'

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a html `<span>` tag which contains text similar to:

```
Example 1:
FOO/BAR/FOO9/10/FOO2 BAR2/FOO3BAR3

Example 2:
FOO/BAR/FOO9/10/FOO4\BAR4/FOO3BAR3/FOO5/BAR5
```

It is used in a mobile environment so space is limited.

When the string contains spaces then the string is divided into two lines, but some strings (see example2) lack any space and they are not fully displayed in the mobile.

All strings use `/` to separate each word. Is there anyway to use `/` to allow break strings same as html does with empty spaces .

I am using bootstrap 3, not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: You say `/` in your question title, but use `\\` in the question itself. So which is it?

Comment: @StephenP it is '/', my mistake

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Modern

The HTML5 [`wbr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) tag "represents a word break opportunity" and was made for this purpose.
I do this with path text that I want to allow to wrap by putting the optional break just before each path separator:

> The file can be found at /etc`<wbr/>`/httpd`<wbr/>`/conf`<wbr/>`/httpd.conf

This allows the path-string to split at any entry.  You can be more selective about where you put the `<wbr>` if you want to break at only certain places.

---

#### Legacy

What I used to do when I wanted paths to allow breaks was to put a [Zero Width Non-Joiner](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) (U+200C) character before each path separator.
My source text would look something like this:

> The path is /foo&zwnj;/bar&zwnj;/foo9&zwnj;/etcetera

This no longer works in (most) modern browsers (tested in Chrome and Firefox) and `wbr` should be used instead. Microsoft Edge, at the time of this writing, ***still*** doesn't support the `<wbr>` tag.

If you have to support both legacy and modern browsers you can use both:

> The file can be found at /etc`<wbr/>`&zwnj;/httpd`<wbr/>`&zwnj;/conf`<wbr/>`&zwnj;/httpd.conf

---

#### Automation

Any of these can be done automatically using a javascript regex if you tag the paths with a class, such as:

> <span class="path">/this/is/my/path</span>

For example, a plain javascript way to add the `zwnj` might look something like this:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('path');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = list[i];
    console.log( item.innerText );
    console.log( item.innerText.replace( /\//g, '&zwnj;/') );
}
```

---

Note - depending on your purpose you could use *Zero Width Space* (U+200B) instead of U+200C
I like to be *semantic*, and to my mind in this case I'm not adding a *space* to the string, I'm adding a place where the string can break — but the choice depends on your purpose.

Comment: As I was using jinja2 templating system it was extremely easy. Following your solution all I had to do was using replace and safe: `{{ mystring|replace("/", "/&zwnj;")|safe }}`

Comment: -1. This is not [what ZWNJ is for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) and moreover it does not work in my browser (Firefox 72). [<wbr/>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#wbr) does.

Comment: Thanks for the links @TheVee - I wrote this when HTML5 was not widely supported in browsers, and at the time `zwnj` worked in Firefox. `<wbr>` _**still**_ [isn't supported in Microsoft Edge](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr#Browser_compatibility), so that suggestion _also_ will not work in some people's browser.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a way to do this where you get to choose the character, but what you can do is play around with the `word-break` css property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

This will allow you to make it so long text without spaces will go on 2 lines, but it will decide where to break it (depending on what CSS property you used). Here are the different options explained:

- `normal` - Use the default line break rule.
- `break-all` - To prevent overflow, word breaks should be inserted between any two characters (excluding Chinese/Japanese/Korean text).
- `keep-all` - 
  Word breaks should not be used for Chinese/Japanese/Korean (CJK) text. Non-CJK text behavior is the same as for normal.
- `break-word` - To prevent overflow, normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line.

Final result example:

```
.some-span {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is useful. Because the kind of information displayed it is really convenient if "word-break" can be done at `/` characters.

Comment: Unfortunately you're out of luck then. Is it possible to use a little bit of javascript?

Comment: I can use javascript, I was thinking in replacing `/` with `/ ` -note the empty space- using `.replace(/\//g, "\/ ")`.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely how I would do it if you're unable to edit the text being rendered.